# Hide a list item if the next siblings are all hidden

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="title">A</li>
  <li class="item" style="display: none">a1</li>
  <li class="item" style="display: none">a2</li>

  <li class="title">B</li>
  <li class="item" style="display: none">b1</li>
  <li class="item">b2</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to create a JavaScript function which checks if the two list items after A are both set to display: none. If they're both set to display: none, then set their title "A" to display: none as well.

I want the script to do the checking for B as well, but don't hide "B" because not all the siblings after it are set to display: none.

I'm thinkering how to proceed for a few hours now but have no idea. Can you give me some ideas how can I do that, not necessarily code, just ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the code that determines what display is for the items?

Comment: Are you using plain js or some library as jQuery?

Comment: show your html and your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all `li.title` and walk down all the next siblings of each `li.title` instance that are `.item` using [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) and store in array.

Then check that array of item siblings for all hidden or not and use that determination what to do with display for current instance of `li.title`

```js
const titles = document.querySelectorAll('li.title');

Array.from(titles).forEach(li => {
  const items = [];
  let next = li.nextElementSibling;

  while (next && next.matches('.item')) {
    items.push(next);
    next = next.nextElementSibling;
  }

  const hide = items.every(n => n.style.display === 'none')

  if (hide) {
    li.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    li.style.removeProperty('display')
  }


})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="title">A</li><!-- should get hidden-->
  <li class="item" style="display: none">a1</li>
  <li class="item" style="display: none">a2</li>

  <li class="title" style="display: none">B</li><!-- should get shown -->
  <li class="item" style="display: none">b1</li>
  <li class="item">b2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @charlietfl is a pretty good one. But in case you have no problem with using jQuery, I find the below code a bit simpler.

You can learn more about nextAll() [here](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/).

```
const titles = $('.title');

titles.each(function() {
    const siblings = $(this).nextAll().slice(0, 2);
    const siblingsWithDisplayNone = siblings.filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('display') == 'none'
    });
    if (siblings.length === siblingsWithDisplayNone.length) {
        $(this).css('display', 'none')
    }
});
```

See it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/82qcv1dn/)

Comment: Can even simplify the filter using `:hidden` selector ... `siblings.filter(':hidden')`. Might also look at using `nextUntil()` which doesn't require slicing a hard code length